# Ansible split returning multiple indexes

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to use split with Ansible to return 2 different indexes, in the example below (which doesn't work) let's say I want to set my_split to 'ad':

```
my_string: "a-b-c-d"
my_split: "{{  my_string.split('-')[0,3]|join() }}"
```

All documentation I can find only shows examples returning 1 index and I can't find any references to what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *Set my_split to 'ad'*

A: The tasks

```
- set_fact:
    my_split: "{{ [0,3]|map('extract',my_string.split('-'))|join() }}"
- debug:
    var: my_split
```

give

```
"my_split": "ad"
```

---

The problem is the selection of the first and fourth elements of the sequence. The expression below

```
my_string.split('-')[0,3]
```

fails

> The error was: list object has no element (0, 3)

Instead, it's possible to use *map* and *extract*. See [Extracting values from containers](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#extracting-values-from-containers).